# Difficulty solving this algebraic expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

First time posting here.
Here is how the original equation is presented:

$$
0.62\% = \left[\left(1 + \frac{0.50\%}{365}\right)^{42}\cdot\left(1 + \frac{\left(P \cdot 0.75\% + \left(1 - P\right) \cdot 0.50\%\right)}{365}\right)^{49} - 1\right]\cdot\frac{365}{91}
$$

I know the correct answer to $P$ is $88.79\%$.
https://www.mathway.com/Algebra confirms this. Although the steps they give don't seem to me to be what a normal person would do.

However, I can't seem to get the correct answer by hand.

I start by multiplying both sides by $\dfrac{91}{365}$ and solving the first term, with no $x$, as $1.00057550$.

I then divide both sides by $1.00057550$

Add one to both sides.

Take the $49^\text{th}$ root of both sides and proceed from there.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please do not use tags that you do not understand. This does not look like a problem that can reasonably be done by hand.

Comment: "However, I am not sure how to get the nicely rendered output of AsciiMath to render nicely in this forum." : Use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: If $\alpha$ denotes the left-hand side of the equation after taking the $49^\mathrm{th}$ root, the next step is $365(\alpha-1) = 0.75\%\cdot P + 0.50\%\cdot(1-P)$, hence an affine equation in $P$, that is why you will then factorize $P$ in order to get $0.25\%\cdot P + 0.50\%$ on the right-hand side. I let you finish.